# had dual boot installation, but default installation Elementary OS 7 wiped out Windows partition

Tags: system-installation, dual-boot

I had a dual boot installation working well, but the default installation of Elementary OS 7.0 repartitioned my disk and wiped out Windows10. So now I guess I have to manually repartition the disk and reinstall Windows (not something I do every day!).

I believe I have a recovery USB around somewhere; could that enable me to recover my old installation? Or do I have to go out and buy Windows10 and start all over from scratch?

Please advise!

Comment: Welcome to eOS. Before wiping partitions, are you sure that the Windows partition is wiped? Linux will not do that without being told to do so, which means your data may still be there 

Comment: lsblk shows a 263G partition mounted as "/boot/efi" and another 477G partition with data-root mountd as "/" and data-swap / cryptswap (not mountd of course). The disk is only about 500G in size so I presume the latter size is cumulative? In any case there's no partition for Windows anymore that I can see.

Comment: Make that "a 263M partition mounted as /boot/efi".

Comment: That is quite unfortunate 